# Regular Expression PHP not validating correctly

Tags: php, regex, validation, preg-match

I am trying to write a regex for my code, the regex is used to validate the phone number format, the first two digits should be either 01,04,05,06,07,08,09 followed by a dash (-) and followed by 6 digits only.

I used the following regex: `0[1456789]{1}-[0-9]{6}`.
I used the following site to make sure my regex is working correctly: [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) and I'm testing it on the following `01-123456`

However, when I run my code, my function returns as if the number is invalid, which is not.

Here is my code:

```
function validHomePhone () {
    global $home_phone;

    $home_phone_regex = "0[1456789]{1}-[0-9]{6}";
    return preg_match($home_phone_regex, $home_phone);
}
```

Why am I getting such results?

Comment: Don't you need a delimiter in your regex?

Comment: I would also like to recommend a simplified version of your regex `/0[14-9]-\d{6}/`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enclose the expression in a [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), like this:

```
/0[1456789]{1}-[0-9]{6}/
```

You should also add the beginning- and end-of-string anchors, otherwise your expression will match anything that *contains* a valid number:

```
/^0[1456789]{1}-[0-9]{6}$/
```

And while we 're at it, the `{1}` quantifier is redundant:

```
/^0[1456789]-[0-9]{6}$/
```

Finally, `[1456789]` can be reduced to `[14-9]`. Personally I would not do this because IMHO it reduces readability for no real gain, but it's something that might be useful somewhere else.

Comment: As an aside your function should take a parameter $home_phone, instead of a global $home_phone function validHomePhone($home_phone) and erase the global line.

Comment: I tried first with just `/` at the beginning and at the end, but didn't try with the `^` and `$`, I though since it worked without them, there wouldn't be a need for them

Thanks Jon

Comment: @aizen92: Also pay attention to beiller's comment above, he's 200% right.